# How to display items with image in p:selectManyCheckbox

Tags: image, jsf, primefaces, selectmanycheckbox

I need to display `<p:selectManyCheckbox>` items with images. I tried to display images with in `<p:selectOneRadio>`. It works fine. I am programmatically adding components on UI. This is my code.

```
answerRadio.setLayout("custom"); //answerRadio is SelectOneRadio
customPnl = (PanelGrid) app.createComponent(PanelGrid.COMPONENT_TYPE);
            customPnl.setId("pnl"+qstnCnt);
            customPnl.setColumns(3);
radioBtn = (RadioButton) app.createComponent(RadioButton.COMPONENT_TYPE);
                        radioBtn.setId("opt"+qstnAnsIndx);
                        radioBtn.setFor("ID of answerRadio");
                        radioBtn.setItemIndex(ansIndx);
                        customPnl.getChildren().add(radioBtn);

outPnl.getChildren().add(answerRadio); //outPnl is OutputPanel that include answerRadio
outPnl.getChildren().add(customPnl);
```

That's `<p:selectOneRadio>` with images.

I'd like to use `<p:selectManyCheckbox>` in same way. But PrimeFaces has only a `<p:radioButton>` for custom layoue and not a `<p:checkbox>` like that. How can I achieve it anyway? How can I display `<p:selectManyCheckbox>` items with images ?

Comment: As to declaring/creating components: there's **nothing** which is impossible in XHTML and only possible in Java. That Java is basically an unreadable mess as compared to XHTML `<p:selectOneRadio>`/`<p:radioButton>`. I strongly recommend to stop declaring/creating components in the controller and instead to it in the view, like every other sane JSF developer does.

Comment: So what do i need to do?

Comment: Just use XHTML. That's so much more readable and maintenance friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible with [`<p:selectManyCheckbox>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/manyCheckbox.xhtml). Your best bet is to just use a bunch of [`<p:selectBooleanCheckbox>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/booleanCheckbox.xhtml) components instead and change the model to be `Map<Entity, Boolean>` instead of `List<Entity>`. You can loop over it using `<ui:repeat>`.

E.g. (normal XHTML variant; I am not going to advocate the Java `createComponent()` equivalent):

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.entities}" var="entity">
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.selection[entity]}" />
    ... (you can put here image, label, anything)
</ui:repeat>
```

with

```
private List<Entity> entites; 
private Map<Entity, Boolean> selection;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    entities = service.list();
    selection = new HashMap<>(); // No need to prefill it!
}
```

To check which ones are selected, loop over the map in action method:

```
List<Entity> selectedEntities = new ArrayList<>();

for (Entry<Entity, Boolean> entry : selection.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue()) {
        selectedEntities.add(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Comment: that is the true way.